# Where does the compiled .ipa reside when I compile and deploy the app for the iOS simulator from Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, ios-simulator

I'd like to be able to pass around the version of my iphone application that was compiled for the simulator.  The idea here is to be able to give copies of the app to different vms where they would deploy the app to the iOS simulator and run some tests.

But after I compile the app for the iOS simulator, I can't find the darn *.ipa.  Does anyone know where it resides?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There’s no .ipa—Xcode copies the `.app` bundle by itself into the simulator. You can check:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourProject-<some garbage>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/
```

(swap Debug for Release if you’re looking to distribute a release build, obviously), or, alternately, get the version that’s actually installed in the simulator from:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<OS version>/Applications/<some UUID>/.
```

You can copy that app bundle into another simulator by creating an arbitrarily-named folder in the above `Applications` directory and placing the `.app` inside it.

Comment: really. great that you point out the 'garbage' part. i initially dont even bat an eye on that lengthy directory >.<

Answer (score 21):

You can see where it is putting your build products by looking on:

```
Xcode Menu-> Preferences-> Locations
```

Or if you have project Specific settings they will be found by looking on

```
Xcode Menu-> File-> Project Settings
```

I think it builds the ipas from the products in those locations and loads them into the simulator. So you might not find an actual .ipa there you find .app in these locations.

If you want an ipa. Do an Archive build.
Do an Ad Hoc distribution and save the resulting .ipa to your desktop.

Comment: This answer should have been accepted, above one is no more valid

Answer (score 1):

have you already tried the following location???

Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: Well, I hadn't tried that.  But I don't have that directory.  What makes you say that one?

Comment: well, its a standard directory where XCode stores its bundles for distribution...

Comment: The "Developer" is most likely in your library, but you probably just can't see it using Finder.   So I clicked on SPOTLIGHT SEARCH (the search icon in the far upper right corner of FINDER on the mac computer).  Then paste in the whole path that is shown when you look at {     Xcode Menu-> File-> Project Settings    }.  Then you should be able to see the contents of the archive.  On my mac, by default, this path is:   {  /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives   }
}